# Am I being scammed?

Tags: fraud

So this guy on instagram claims he's a bitcoin miner, and has a lot of money in his bitcoin wallet. He says he needs the username and password to my banking account to make deposits because he can't make withdraws outside of the U.S & Canada. He also claims that he will be making daily deposits of $2500.00 which I will keep 30% of and send the rest back. When I asked how I will send his money to him, first he said through Money Gram(MG), then when I asked him again he said MG won't be necessary since he wants steam cards. I didn't go through with it yet because I don't want to give him my login information. Am I being ripped off?

Comment: Yes, this look a lot like a scam.

Comment: So very obviously a scam!

Comment: It's a good thing your brain was switched on, with some it switches off when quick money announces itself

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely, 100% a scam. You are being recruited to be a money mule. Stop dealing with this person *immediately*. For one thing, your username and password are not needed to deposit funds.

At least part of the scam is probably this: The scammer has bought passwords to bank accounts that have been stolen with malware. He will use those credentials to transfer stolen funds to your account and you will launder the funds for him. Eventually, the people whose accounts were hacked will complain to their banks and police and the payments will be reversed. You will wind up owing the bank a lot of money, the scammer will disappear, and you will have a very bad time.

**This may not be the exact scam, but it's 100% definitely a scam one way or another.**

Answer (score 1):

This is a scam, if you have concerns that aren’t explained by any reasonable standard, be very cautious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely a scam. Please don't do it. Don't give anyone your bank account's password. And also maybe it would be good act to put some screenshots and show his/her/their instagram account name, so no one will get scammed -at least- by your scammer in the future.

Comment: I don't know how to upload images to this question but his username on instagram is @avela709